# Effective Action behaviour in $SU(N)$ Gauge Theory in Solodukhin

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, regularization, 1pi-effective-action

In Solodukhins paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3117
he says that the effective Action of a 4D CFT has the general structure:
$$W = \frac{a_0}{\epsilon^4} +\frac{a_1}{\epsilon^2}+a_2 \ln{\epsilon} +\omega(g^{\alpha}).$$

$\epsilon$ is the UV-cutoff. I would like to know, how one explains this form, he does not do it unfortunately.

Comment: He did say what $\epsilon$ is below Eq 1.1: it's the UV cutoff for regularization.

Comment: You are right, thanks for noticing! I first thought that one could also call any regulator of a QFT a UV cutoff but I guess that would not do the name justice :)